# bootstrap multiselect dropdown width 100%

Tags: css, bootstrap-multiselect

I have been using [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) in my web app for about 9 months now. I've been styling the width of the dropdown to be 100% like this:

```
    ul.multiselect-container {
      width: 100% !important;
    }

.dropdown-menu {width:100% !important;}
```

I just got the new version because it had an extra configuration option (onDeselectAll). Now the dropdown width is not 100%. Looking at the styling in the elements console it looks like my css should still work:

We can see in the photo of the css that `.dropdown-menu {width:100% !important}` is being overridden but I'm not sure what by.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you can share the site to inspect or a fiddle with the code?

Comment: @Sterling struggling to get the bootstrap multiselect working in the jsfiddle but here it is https://jsfiddle.net/u0m6tzsp/1/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The below minimal example is working fine, so Bootstrap Multiselect is not override the styling. But note that in your case `.dropdown-menu` and `.multiselect-container` refer to the very same elements (the `ul`, like in the example below. So applying the styling to both classes, like you did is not necessary and may cause what you see in the inspector.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#multiselect').multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '400px'
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .multiselect-container {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had already got mine working and forgot to answer but your example works too so is a good solution. I needed to add `position: relative` in my specific case: `ul.multiselect-container {
  width: 100% !important;
  position: relative !important; }`. Really nice plugin by the way. I have also added selectable optgroups now and it works perfectly. Thanks for your work on it! :)

Comment: `buttonWidth: '400px'` and  `.multiselect-container {
        width: 100% !important;
    }` worked for me

Comment: Can it be done using bootstrap-5? that is with pure Javascript.

Answer (score 25):

I used the `buttonWidth` parameter that `.multiselect` gives you similar to David Stutz. However, I put the `'100%'` right in the parameter.

```
<body>
    <select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#multiselect').multiselect({
                buttonWidth: '100%'
            });
        //caret is in the middle, switch it to right
        $(".caret").css('float', 'right');
        $(".caret").css('margin', '8px 0');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried setup `buttonWidth` and `.multiselect-container` but it did not work for me.

This is my way to set select tag to 100% within `form-group` class, it may help someone.

```
.bootstrap-select:not([class*="col-"]):not([class*="form-control"]):not(.input-group-btn){
       width:100%;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.9/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
 <style> 
  .bootstrap-select:not([class*="col-"]):not([class*="form-control"]):not(.input-group-btn){
   width:100%;
  }
 </style>

</head>

<body>
 
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="tags">Select tags list</label>
    <div class="form-group">
     <select class="selectpicker input-large" multiple data-live-search="true">
      <option>COAL_5CD-PT07</option>
      <option>COAL_5CD-PT08</option>
      <option>COAL_5CD-PT09</option>
      <option>LNG_TI37130</option>
      <option>LNG_TI37230</option>
      <option>CCP_AB1HAD45CP900_ZQ01</option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.9/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 <script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

   $('select').selectpicker();

  });
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```